# UML Class Self Association

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I just cant wrap my head around the self association. So I thought up of an example: A class Body is made of many molecules. The molecule is itself made of many molecules.

This is my solution: 
[image]

Comment: Simply spoken: correct.

Comment: nah. I say thank you! I still need to practice more

Answer (score 0):

### What is a self-association?

An [association](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html) is a relation between two classes, that says some instances of one class may be related to some instances of the other class.

In the case of a [self-association](https://online.visual-paradigm.com/diagrams/templates/class-diagram/self-association/), the two classes simply happen to be the same.  This means that some instances of the class may be related to some other instances of the class.

This can be useful whenever an object is related to another object of the same class, for example relation between persons, or relation between nodes of graph, hierachies, etc...

### Conclusion

Your example is a perfect example for such a self-association. In your case,  any molecule could be broken down into micromolecules.

### More thoughts

A more general variation of your molecule design could be the [composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern):

[image]

This makes the difference between a general concept (e.g. molecule) which could be be decomposed further (I'm not gifted in chemistry, but [macromolecule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macromolecule) sounded good for me - excuse my ignorance if it's not the case) and elementary molecules that cannot.

This design is especially useful for hierarchical decompositions. It avoids the self-association and allows to have different behaviors depending on whether the object can be subdivided further or not.